# Passing state to other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

If I had react router routes set up like this:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home}>
        <Route path='/name' component={Name} />
        <Route path="/level" component={Level} />
        <Route path="/level1" component={Level1} />
        <Route path="/level2" component={Level2} />
        <Route path="/result" component={Result} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

and had a component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Name extends Component {
    getInitialState() {
        return { username: '' }
    },
    onUpdateUser: function (e) {
        this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
              <div claassName="col-md-12">
                <div className="nameBox">
                  <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Desiered Username" onChange={this.onUpdateUser} value={this.state.username} />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

how would I make `username` available to the global scope? Would I have to pass it in through the router or could I define it a different way?

Basically once the username is set, I want onSubmit to take it to the /level route and with the username.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing ES6 class notation with React.createClass helper method calls, you might want to consider a more consistent approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either keep that state in a container component(maybe the place where you have your routes).Ex.:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Container extends Component {
    constructor() {
      this.state = {username: ''};
    }

    updateUserName = (username) => {
      this.setState({username});
    }

    render() {
     return <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Home}> 
            <Route path='/name' component={() =><Name updateUserName ={this.updateUserName}/>} />
            <Route path="/level" component={Level} />
            <Route path="/level1" component={Level1} />
            <Route path="/level2" component={Level2} />
            <Route path="/result" component={Result} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
}
}
```

And then in your component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Name extends Component {
    onUpdateUser: function (e) {
        this.props.updateUserName(e.target.value);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
              <div claassName="col-md-12">
                <div className="nameBox">
                  <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Desiered Username" onChange={this.onUpdateUser} value={this.state.username} />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Or start using libraries like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs) if you're aiming for a bigger project, they will keep your application state out of your React layer so you can make this data available to components that aren't directly related in your component tree.

Comment: I really love the fact that you mentioned MobX. I would have never known that would have existed. It looks like a really cool library and can't wait to play with it in the morning! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best approach would be a global state control (like Flux/Redux).

But you can reach something similar with `react-router` and `params` on URL. What I would do is:

- onClick submit function
- redirect to your other Route with params
- access your username on other page

Example below:

```
onClickFunction() {
  router.push({
    pathname: '/level1/' + this.state.username
  })
}
render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
              <div claassName="col-md-12">
                <div className="nameBox">
                  <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Desiered Username" onChange={this.onUpdateUser} value={this.state.username} />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick={ onClickFunction }>Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And on your , you should do something like that:

```
<Route path="/level/:username" component={Level} />
```

Do not forget to bind your onClickFunction on constructor to avoid problems with **this**

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm very glad you showed me the router.push() method. That will come in handy. What problems would arise in this? Do you have specific use cases?

Comment: The specific use case is when you want to:
1. Do an action
2. Wait or not for an API answer
3. Redirect to another page with or without some information (username in your case).

The problem sometimes is that you do not want to redirect just after the action, but store the username for later. In that case is not possible